# Can the dimension of a highest-weight irrep be a non-integer?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry

This is my first time using stack exchange, so I am sorry for any formatting errors.
I am working on implementing the Racah-Speiser algorithm for $\mathfrak{psu}(2,2|4)$ superconformal multiplets. I am now trying to do a consistency check for the multiplets my program generates, and thought of using dimension formulae for all representations in the multiplet. For that, I am comparing with formulas from https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0209056, and this works well enough for long and short multiplets, but not semi-short. For example, for the $\mathcal{C}^{(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4})}$-multiplet [$\Delta=3.5,k=1,p=0,q=0,j=0,\bar{j}=0$] the formula given in the paper leads to a dimension of 39850,6666666666, while by adding up the multiplicities of every Racah-Speiser module times the irrep´s dimension, I get 137472.

Does it make sense to have a non-integer as the dimension of a multiplet? Intuitively this does not seem correct, since it would mean that the sum of dimensions of the fields the representations act in is not a whole number, but maybe I am missing something. Is it correct to assume that the dimension of the module is this sum? And how would I generally go about calculating the dimension of the whole multiplet?